# EZ Text API & ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Anyone have any experience with the EZ Text API and ColdFusion?  I'm trying this call:

```
<cfhttp url="https://app.eztexting.com/sending/messages?format=JSON"
     method="POST" result="objGet" charset="utf-8">
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
   <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="User" value="xxx" />
   <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Password" value="xxx"/>
   <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="PhoneNumbers[]" value="9999999999"  />
   <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="MessageTypeID" value="1" /> 
   <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Message" value="Hello" />
</cfhttp>
```

... which is returning a status code of `200` and trying to redirect to their home page.

Their tech support can only tell me that I should use curl which is not installed on the server that I need it on.  I have used curl successfully in my devel environment, so I'm sure that the url and credentials are good.

Any thoughts are welcome!  Thanks.

Comment: 1. Could you post the curl code that does succeed? 2. For authentication, try  "username" and "password" to the parent cfhttp tag

Comment: Thanks @ageax!  I tried username and password with no success.

Comment: Post the curl call that *does* work, so we can see what's different. Also, could you post a link to the API docs?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Does your ColdFusion server have the cert installed to be able to connect to HTTPS?

Comment: Always a good thing to check. Though if the call really is returning 200, it sounds like the certs are okay.

Comment: I think the 200 response is actually on whatever redirect is sending them back to the home page after a failed login. I don't think the original message is being captured. If you try running the above code ( bless you CommandBox ) with the bad credentials ( xxx/xxx ), you'll still get a 200 response back with the redirected credentials of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using the [REST API](https://www.eztexting.com/developers/sms-api-documentation/rest#CatSending). If yes, the reason it's redirecting you to the home page is because the URL is incorrect. Apparently the format parameter is *case sensitive*. So `?format=JSON` should be changed to `?format=json` (all lower case).

Making that minor adjustment to your code example:

```
<cfhttp url="https://app.eztexting.com/sending/messages?format=json"
     method="POST" result="objGet" charset="utf-8">
   ...
</cfhttp>
```

... returns the expected JSON response for bogus credentials, instead of the html for the home page:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "Status": "Failure",
    "Code": 401,
    "Errors": [
      "Authorization Required"
    ]
  }
}
```

Once you get past this issue, you may want to double check your `formfield` names. The API lists the parameter name `PhoneNumbers`, not `PhoneNumbers[]`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I knew is was something simple but the EZ Text tech support could not help.  As soon as I changed JSON to lower case it worked!

Comment: Yeah, you get so accustomed to CF's flexibility. I know case sensitivity issues trip me up every so when working with other languages.  Anyway, glad it helped.